# Can you leave children in a car while you pay for fuel in Australia

Tags: australia

There are laws that prohibit leaving children in a car alone that can result in fines and court attendance.

Under these laws can you be fined for leaving children in a car at a service station while paying for petrol

Answer (score 3):

### Yes, maybe

The legislation varies by state but [s494](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/vic/num_act/cyafa200596o2005298/s494.html) of the Victorian Children, Young Persons and Families Act is typical.

> A person who has the control or charge of a child must not leave the child without making reasonable provision for the child's supervision and care for a time which is unreasonable having regard to all the circumstances of the case.

If the child is 17 years old then the circumstances are such that it is *not* unreasonable to leave them, even for a period of days. If the child is 17 days old, even 30 seconds may be unreasonable.